# Почему метод push() добавляет запятую?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Столкнулась с проблемой следующего рода. Необходимо динамически рендерить с сервера данные...

Данные получаю в таком формате

```
task={'1': [{'text': 'Задача раз'}, {'date': 'Сегодня'}, {'acept': 'Готово'}], 
      '2': [{'text': 'Задача два'}, {'date': 'Завтра'}, {'acept': 'В процессе'}], 
}
```

Для обработки и рендеринга использую следующий код

```js
    function getAndRenderTasks(){
  $.getJSON("/tasks/api/v1.0/tasks", function (data) {
  
  var tasks = [] // Место хранения всех задач
  
  $.each( data, function(key, val) { // Перебираем ключи и значения
             // пришедших в ответе

    var taskData = [] // Данные одной задачи

   for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { // хешы задачи
      
      $.each(val[i], function(key1, val1){ // достаем данные из хеша
     taskData.push( "<div class='"+key1+"'>"+val1+"</div>") // ложим добытые значения в массив таска
    })
   }

   tasks.push( "<div taskId='"+key+"'>"+taskData+"</div>") // добавляем в общий список

  })
   
  $( "<div/>", { // Рендерим список
      "class": "my-new-list",
      html: tasks.join("_______________")
    }).appendTo( "body")
  })
 }
```

На выходе получаю следующее

```
Задача раз
,
Сегодня
,
Готово
_______________
Задача два
,
Завтра
,
В процессе
```

как убрать запятые? Они мне не нужны...

Comment: Обратите внимание, что Ваш код выполняется неверно. В консоль ничего не выводится.

Comment: я добавила просто что бы форматирование было...

Comment: Когда обращаетесь к пользователю, ставьте @ и его ник. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5022/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что у вас `taskData` — массив, а его представление в строке является перечисление значений через запятую.

Пример:

```js
var test = [1,2,3].toString();

console.log(test);
```

Чтобы их объединить в строку, воспользуйтесь методом [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) c "пустотой" в качестве разделителя:

```
taskData.join('')
```

Всё....

---

Итог:

```js
task = { '1': [{'text': 'Задача раз'}, {'date': 'Сегодня'}, {'acept': 'Готово'}],
        '2': [{'text': 'Задача два'}, {'date': 'Завтра'}, {'acept': 'В процессе'}],
};

//var tasks = [] // Место хранения всех задач
var tasks = []; // Место хранения всех задач
$.each(task, function(key, val) { // Перебираем ключи и значения
  // пришедших в ответе

  var taskData = []; // Данные одной задачи

  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { // хешы задачи

    $.each(val[i], function(key1, val1) { // достаем данные из хеша
      taskData.push("<div class='" + key1 + "'>" + val1 + "</div>"); // ложим добытые значения в массив таска
    });
  }

  tasks.push("<div taskId='" + key + "'>" + (taskData.join('')) + "</div>"); // добавляем в общий список    
});

$("<div/>", { // Рендерим список
  "class": "my-new-list",
  html: tasks.join("_______________")
}).appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-new-list"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ!!!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что запятые добавляются не при join, а в момент сбора следующей строки

```
"<div taskId='"+key+"'>"+taskData+"</div>"
```

где *taskData* так же является массивом. В этом случае он приводится к строке, при этом у него вызывается метод *toString*, результат которого эквивалентен вызову `array.join()`, что в свою очередь эквивалентно вызову `array.join(',')`

Для того, чтобы убрать запятую нужно вызвать join напрямую, например:

```js
var task = {
  '1': [{
    'text': 'Задача раз'
  }, {
    'date': 'Сегодня'
  }, {
    'acept': 'Готово'
  }],
  '2': [{
    'text': 'Задача два'
  }, {
    'date': 'Завтра'
  }, {
    'acept': 'В процессе'
  }],
}
var tasks = [] // Место хранения всех задач

$.each(task, function(key, val) { // Перебираем ключи и значения
  // пришедших в ответе

  var taskData = [] // Данные одной задачи

  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { // хешы задачи

    $.each(val[i], function(key1, val1) { // достаем данные из хеша
      taskData.push("<div class='" + key1 + "'>" + val1 + "</div>") // ложим добытые значения в массив таска
    })
  }

  tasks.push("<div taskId='" + key + "'>" + taskData.join('') + "</div>") // добавляем в общий список

})

$("<div/>", { // Рендерим список
  "class": "my-new-list",
  html: tasks.join("_______________")
}).appendTo("body");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ!

Comment: @ElectroGirl я был первым :-/